# Task.WhenAll hangs out if there are no tasks to complete

Tags: c#, mongodb, asynchronous

I have method that inserts list of objects into Mongo DB.

```
public class StorageService : IStorageService
{
  public Task<BulkWriteResult<Option>> SaveOptions(List<Option> contracts)
  {
    var context = new MongoContext<Option>();
    return context.SaveCollection(contracts);
  }
}

var optionIds = Task
  .WhenAll(storageService.SaveOptions(optionDetails.Values.ToList()))
  .Result;
```

If list of contracts is empty, then there is no objects to insert into DB, and no tasks to complete, so Task.WhenAll keeps running indefinitely creating a deadlock.

**Question**

Is there a way to return empty / completed task if list is empty, or maybe there is a better solution of how to get results of insert, but at the same time, correctly handle case when there are no results?

**Update #1**

Approximate structure.

WebApi - MVC project

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public Response<int> DownloadOptions([FromBody] ContractSelector data)
{
  .. some controller code

  var optionIds = Task
    .WhenAll(storageService.SaveOptions(optionDetails.Values.ToList()))
    .Result;

  // this method should gather data from multiple APIs
  // so I need Task.Result of all previous operations
  // I could make this method async and use await, but it's not the case here
}
```

Class Library project, .NET 4.6.1

```
public class StorageService : IStorageService
{
  public Task<BulkWriteResult<Option>> SaveOptions(List<Option> contracts)
  {
    var context = new MongoContext<Option>();
    return context.SaveCollection(contracts);
  }
}
```

**Update #2**

Why there is no use for async / await. There are 2 external API calls, one is to get general info about some asset, and the second one is to get prices for this asset, I can't change this. So, if I want to get all info in one method I must request general info, then **Wait** for **Result**, and, based on general info, request relevant prices. After this, I want to save gathered info into DB and return list of saved IDs in the response to my API.

Sequence of calls

```
1. UI
2. WebApi MVC Controller
3. Class Library
3.1 Request asset info - wait for the result
3.2 Get asset info - request prices for selected assets - wait for the result
3.3 Get asset info and prices info - save everything to DB - return response

var contracts = Task.WhenAll(optionService.GetContracts(params)).Result;
var prices = Task.WhenAll(optionService.GetOptionDetails(contracts)).Result;
var ids = Task.WhenAll(storageService.SaveOptions(prices.Values.ToList()));
```

So, response depends on 3.3, 3.3 depends on 3.2, 3.2 depends on 3.1. If you know how to turn it all to a non-blocking call, I'm all ears. For now I think that 3 blocking calls in 1 HTTP request are better than 3 separate async HTTP requests.

Comment: a quick test here shows that `Task.WhenAll` does *not*, in fact, stall when no tasks are incoming... `var nothingToDo = new List<Task>(); Task.WhenAll(nothingToDo); Console.WriteLine("All done");` - so... there may be an incorrect assumption here. Also, you should *almost never* use `.Result` or `.Wait()`, and this scenario is definitely more on the "never" side than the "almost"

Comment: You only have one task regardless if there none, one or more contracts, so you don’t even need WhenAll. That being said, like Marc Gravell mentioned don’t use Result or Wait, and instead use await if need to await tasks/get their results.

Comment: Under what framework does `optionIds` run?

Comment: This method should gather data from several APIs, so I need to get results of this call, and I can't see any alternative to Result here

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto if you mean .NET, I'm currently using Mongo DB driver 2.7.0 in .NET standard library project with .NET 4.6.1

Comment: My bad, I meant type of application (WinForms, WPF, Xamarin, ASP.NET, ASP.NET Core...?)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I have Mongo repository in ".NET standard library" project which is used in another "Web API - MVC" project. Task.WhenAll is a part of WebApi and SaveOptions is a part of Class Library. Explained below.

Comment: ASP.NET Web API is optimized for asynchronous code. Why is `DownloadOptions` not `async Task<Response<int>> DownloadOptions`? You shouldn't block threads with `Result` like that. And even more, you shouldn't create a `Task` whose only purpose is to wait for another `Task`. At best (read, *worst*), it should just be `storageService.SaveOptions(optionDetails.Values.ToList()).Result`. But you should really just be using `await storageService.SaveOptions(optionDetails.Values.ToList())`

Comment: @Camillo I added additional description in Update #2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't explain in details, but looks like issue was caused by **incompatibility between .NET framework and Mongo DB driver**. Currently I'm using .NET 4.6.1 and Mongo 2.6.1 and it works fine.

Yesterday any try to save an empty list of objects into Mongo DB caused a deadlock.

Then I tried to refactor code and install the latest version of Mongo DB, which is 2.7.0. Now any CRUD operation with Mongo DB returns this error. There is no call stack and more details about this exception.

```
MethodAccessException: Attempt by method 'MongoDB.Driver.ClientSession..ctor(MongoDB.Driver.IMongoClient, MongoDB.Driver.ClientSessionOptions, MongoDB.Driver.IServerSession, Boolean)' to access method 'MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.ClusterClock..ctor()' failed.
```

Then I tried to lower version of Mongo DB to 2.6.1 and when I try to insert empty list of objects I'm getting this exception, which is correct. When I insert at least one record it works as expected.

```
System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred.'
ArgumentException: Must contain at least 1 request.
Parameter name: requests
```

Testing code

```
var item = new Demo
{
  Symbol = "SomeSymbol",
  Expiration = "2019-01-01"
};

var list = new List<Demo>();

list.Add(item); 
list.Add(item); // if I comment these lines, then Mongo 2.6.1 returns correct exception

var optionIds = Task.WhenAll(storageService.Save(list)).Result;
```

Save method is implemented as a part of [Mongo repository pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42133963/mongodb-and-large-datasets-when-using-a-repository-pattern)

```
public Task<BulkWriteResult<T>> SaveCollection(List<T> items)
{
  var records = new List<ReplaceOneModel<T>>();
  var processes = new List<Task<ReplaceOneResult>>();

  items.ForEach(contract =>
  {
    var record = new ReplaceOneModel<T>(Builders<T>
      .Filter
      .Where(o => o.Id == contract.Id), contract)
    {
      IsUpsert = true
    };

    records.Add(record);
  });

  return Collection.BulkWriteAsync(records);
}
```